# PHP: array with an if statement inside

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Hi all,

Here's my code:

```
if ($value==0)
{
        $array = array(
        "NAMES"            => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
        "LASTNAMES"      => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
        );
}
else 
{
        $array = array(
        "NAMES"            => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
        "LASTNAMES"      => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant"),
        "ITEMPURCHASED"      => array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic")
         );   
}
```

As you can see I'm reapeating the whole array code just because the ITEMPURCHASED element.

Is there a way not to repeat the whole array code? Can an if be used inside the array which adds just the ITEMPURCHASED element? If so, how?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    "NAMES" => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
    "LASTNAMES" => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
);

if ($value != 0){
    $array['ITEMPURCHASED'] = array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic");
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the value to NULL if $value is not equal to 0 by using a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
$array = array(
    "NAMES" => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
    "LASTNAMES" => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant"),
    "ITEMPURCHASED" => ($value != 0) ? array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic") : null
);
```

Comment: The first option you posted works great. fyi only problem with null option is when using a select field the option to select is still there, but the value is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$array = array(
              "NAMES"        => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
              "LASTNAMES"    => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
         );
if($val != 0) {
    $array['ITEMPURCHASED'] = => array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic");
}
```

Just put the common array out of the loop and check the condition and if true then append the remaining ITEMPURCHASED based array to the main array.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $array = array(
    "NAMES"            => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
    "LASTNAMES"      => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
    );
    if($value != 0) {
        $array["ITEMPURCHASED"] = array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do that by following code:

```
$array = $array = array(
        "NAMES"            => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
        "LASTNAMES"      => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
      );
if ($value != 0)
        $array["ITEMPURCHASED"] = array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic");
}
```

Or you can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function of PHP.
then code will be:

```
if ($value != 0)
           $arrar1 = array("ITEMPURCHASED" => array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic"));
            $array = array_merge($array,$array1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
   "NAMES" => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"),
   "LASTNAMES" => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
);

if ($value!=0)
{
    $array["ITEMPURCHASED"] = array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use if inside the array. You could use ternary operators to alter the value depending on some conditions inside the array constructor, but since you don't want to set the item at all that won't be an option either. You can do it like this though:

```
$array = array(
  "NAMES"          => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"), 
  "LASTNAMES"      => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
);

if ($value ! =0)
  $array['ITEMPURCHASED'] = array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you create the array, as in the first part of the if (copy that code before the if)

Then use:

```
if ($value != 0) {
  $array['ITEMPURCHASED'] = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$array = array(
   "NAMES" => array("John", "Sara", "Mark"),
   "LASTNAMES" => array ("Smith", "Lockwood", "Grant")
);

if ($value!=0)
{
    $array["ITEMPURCHASED"] = array ("DVD", "Book", "Comic");
}
```